# loading website name on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implant this: http://jsfiddle.net/QQGfc/168/

**html:**

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="visibility: hidden">
<form>
    <input id="test" value="test" type="button" name="test" />
</form>
```

Loading info,,,

**js:**

```
function message() {
  var x = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
  $("p").html(x);
}
$("#test").click(function () {
  message();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').click();
});
```

to http://van-der-noord.nl/beta
On the jsfiddle it works just fine, but on my site it doesn't! I  can't really find any problems in the console..

> result on jsfiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net//QQGfc/168/show/
>
> result on website: Loading info,,,

So how do I fix this?

Comment: If you've fixed your question, please don't put that into the question (that's not where it belongs), but answer it yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Okay sorry I didn't know I'll do it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to assign on load

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zxz6d7v9/)

```
$(function () {
  $("#test").click(function () {
    message();
  });
  $('#test').click();
});
```

Also change `$("p").html(x);` to for example `$("#sitename").html(x);` and add `id="sitename"` to the `<p>` you want to hold the url

Answer (score -1):

it seems your custom.js is missing, is that where this script is located? I don't see it in the dom

http://van-der-noord.nl/custom.js

Comment: O yeah I used it a while ago for something else<br>
This js is in init.js: http://van-der-noord.nl/beta/js/init.js